# How to check maximum value in group and return product name

Tags: python, pandas

I have table with like this one

```
Product Group Amount
product1    1     10
product2    1     20
product3    2     20
product4    2     30
product5    2     40
product6    3     30
```

I want to find most expensive product within each group and add another 'Most expensive' column

```
Product Group Amount Most_expensive
product1    1     10 product2
product2    1     20 product2
product3    2     20 product5
product4    2     30 product5
product5    2     40 product5
product6    3     30 product6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create `index` by `Product` column, so you can use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['Most_expensive'] = (df.set_index('Product')
                          .groupby('Group')['Amount']
                          .transform('idxmax').values)
print (df)
    Product  Group  Amount Most_expensive
0  product1      1      10       product2
1  product2      1      20       product2
2  product3      2      20       product5
3  product4      2      30       product5
4  product5      2      40       product5
5  product6      3      30       product6
```

Or use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `Series` created by [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
s = (df.sort_values('Amount', ascending=False)
       .drop_duplicates('Group')
       .set_index('Group')['Product'])

df['Most_expensive'] = df['Group'].map(s)
```

Or create dictionary with duplicated `Groups` values - then is used last value of `Product`:

```
d = df.sort_values('Amount').set_index('Group')['Product'].to_dict()
df['Most_expensive'] = df['Group'].map(d)
```

Comment: I think this is more complicated

Comment: @ansev - hmmm, your first solution working only for data sample, generally not.

Comment: Yes and that's why I decided to delete it. But I consider that my current answer is simpler ..

Comment: @ansev - Yes, second answer is more complicated, so added new solution (I think simplier). Btw, if think your answer is best, it is OK, obviously each answerer think same way ;)

Answer (score 0):

What about these 2 steps: first create a dictionary with the maxes of each group:

```
maxes = df.groupby(by='Group').max().to_dict()
```

then easily build the new column by reading the dictionary:

```
df['Most_expensive'] = df['Group'].apply(lambda x: maxes['Product'][x])
```